# Mobile app - Push notifications alternatives?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need push notifications for my app, is GCM the only way to go?
And is GCM only available via Appengine (and Firebase)?

Or can you use it on Heroku and other services?

Is it a big no to use polling or implement your own push notification srvice (which uses polling anyway)?

Does GCM work for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

*I need push notifications for my app, is GCM the only way to go?*

There are other Push Notification Services that are available (check out this [list](http://www.buzinga.com.au/buzz/mobile-push-notification-services/)) other than GCM, and since I haven't really experienced using any other Push Notification Service, I'm gonna refrain from commenting on them.

---

*And is GCM only available via Appengine (and Firebase)? Or can you use it on Heroku and other services?*

I'm not entirely sure what your asking here. But if you're pertaining to integrating them, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29540372/4625829) where GCM was somehow integrated with Heroku (haven't used Heroku before, sorry). On that note, I think it's possible to use it with other services, which ones and how? I don't know. All depends on the use-case and implementation I guess.

So I'm just gonna go on ahead and mention that GCM has it's latest version release last Google I/O, which is now called [firebase-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging).

---

*Is it a big no to use polling or implement your own push notification service (which uses polling anyway)?*

I don't think so. As I mentioned above, it depends on your use-case. But when using GCM/FCM, the implementation will be easier, plus, you'll get access to it's free additional features.

---

*Does GCM work for iOS?*

Yes. Check out the [Setting Up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) doc.

---

Hope this helps. Cheers! :D

Comment: So how's it going @JennieJames? Have you decided? Will you be using GCM? :)

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest using FCM now. It's based on the GCM Core, so pretty much the same, however, it has so much more features, for free. :D